# Connection issue between Asp.Net 4.5 app and SQL Server 2012

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2012, iis-7.5

I have a web forms application that is connecting to a SQL Server 2012 database. When I try to open the connection within the app I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.) ---> ...

I've checked and SQL server is configured to allow remote connections, TCP/IP is enabled, the server is up and I can connect to it via SSMS and Linqpad.

This is occurring when I run the application locally, hitting a local database. I know the connection string works, as I can use the login in SSMS to login and I have a linqpad query that is working with no problem using the same connection string. Also the error occurs when I try to open the connection (i.e. the connection is created successfully).

I'm guessing there is some access/security issues with my configuration of IIS, but I not finding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of frustrating days, I discovered the solution. The problem was that SQL server wasn't setup to use TCP/IP. This is configured in the Sql Server Configuration Manager, under the SQL Serer Network Configuration node, then Protocols for MSSQLSERVER. Make sure TCP/IP is enabled.